# What's the difference between @ComponentScan and @Bean in a context configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-test

There are at least 2 approaches to put Spring beans into a context configutation:

1. Declare a method with `@Bean` inside the configuration class.
2. Put `@ComponentScan` on the configuration class.

I was expecting that there are no difference between the 2 approaches in terms of the resulting Spring beans.

However, I found an example to demonstrate the difference:

```java
// UserInfoService.java

public interface UserInfoService
{
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    String getUserInfo ();
}
```

```java
// UserInfoServiceTest.java

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextHierarchy({
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestSecurityContext.class),
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = UserInfoServiceTest.Config.class)
})
public class UserInfoServiceTest
{
    @Configuration
    public static class Config
    {
        @Bean
        public UserInfoService userInfoService ()
        {
            return new UserInfoServiceImpl();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserInfoService userInfoService;

    @Test
    public void testGetUserInfoWithoutUser ()
    {
        assertThatThrownBy(() -> userInfoService.getUserInfo())
                .isInstanceOf(AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException.class);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void testGetUserInfoWithUser ()
    {
        String userInfo = userInfoService.getUserInfo();
        assertThat(userInfo).isEqualTo("info about user");
    }
```

The above code is to test the security annotation in the service `UserInfoService`. However, it will fail on `testGetUserInfoWithoutUser()`. The reason is that the bean `userInfoService` didn't get proxied by Spring Security. Therefore, the call `userInfoService.getUserInfo()` didn't get blocked by the annotation `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")`.

However, if I replace the `@Bean` annotation with `@ComponentScan`, everything will start to work. That is, the bean `userInfoService` will get proxied and the call `userInfoService.getUserInfo()` will be blocked by the `@PreAuthorize` annotation.

Why are the approaches between the `@Bean` and `@ComponentScan` different? Did I miss something?

P.S. The full example is [here](https://github.com/johnlinp/spring-playground/tree/demo-test-security) and the above mentioned fix is [here](https://github.com/johnlinp/spring-playground/commit/ea8443a263309224c8e6eb6303a341d0dce3ba14).

Comment: If using `@Bean`, shouldn't you annotate the factory method with `@PreAuthorize` too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `@ContextHierarchy` will create multiple spring contexts with parent children hierarchy. In your case, `TestSecurityContext`  defines the bean configuration for the parent context while `UserInfoServiceTest.Config` defines for the children context.

If there is no `@ComponentScan` on the `UserInfoServiceTest.Config` , the security related beans are defined in the parent context which are invisible to the `UserInfoService` bean in the children context , and hence it does not get proxied by Spring Security.

On the other hand , if you define `@ComponentScan` on the `UserInfoServiceTest.Config`  , it will also scan all the `@Configuration` beans from the package that containing `UserInfoService` (and all of its sub package) . Because `TestSecurityContext` is also inside this package and hence it get scanned and the security related beans are also configured for the children context. `UserInfoService` in children context will then get proxied by Spring Security.(Note : In this case ,both the parent and children context has their own set of security related beans)

By the way , if you just need a single context , you can simply use `@ContextConfiguration` :

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {TestSecurityContext.class,UserInfoServiceTest.Config.class})
public class UserInfoServiceTest {

    public static class Config {
        @Bean
        public UserInfoService userInfoService() {
            return new UserInfoServiceImpl();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the the `UserInfoService` bean in the child context is invisible to the security related beans in the parent context? Your second paragraph seems describe the other way around?

Comment: Yes. They are the same. The point is that the security related beans are only visible and apply to the beans in the same context.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the answer.